# XJC 4.0.1 Producing Error "External parsing is disabled" Despite Turning Feature On in jaxp.properties

Tags: xjc

I am getting an error using XJC 4.0.1 on Windows 10 while attempting to generate Java source from a DTD:

```
C:\Users\mbmas_000\workspace\EnergyMeterMonitor>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.3.1\bin\java" --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\jaxb-ri\mod\jakarta.xml.bind-api.jar";"C:\Program Files\Java\jaxb-ri\mod\jaxb-xjc.jar";"C:\Program Files\Java\jaxb-ri\mod\jaxb-core.jar";"C:\Program Files\Java\jaxb-ri\mod\jaxb-impl.jar";"C:\Program Files\Java\jaxb-ri\mod\jakarta.activation-api.jar" --add-modules com.sun.xml.bind  -m com.sun.tools.xjc -dtd -d generatedsrc -p com.mbm.test http://www.egauge.net/DTD/egauge-hist.dtd
parsing a schema...
[WARNING] Are you trying to compile DTD? Support for DTD is experimental. You may enable it by using the -dtd option.
unknown location

[ERROR] External parsing is disabled. Cannot parse URI: http://www.egauge.net/DTD/egauge-hist.dtd
unknown location

Failed to parse a schema.
```

Here is the contents of `jaxp.properties`:

```
javax.xml.accessExternalSchema = all
javax.xml.accessExternalDTD = all
```

Here is proof XJC is reading `jaxp.properties`:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?  I find it strange that XJC also gives me warning about trying to compile a DTD and suggesting that I specify `-dtd` when I have specified `-dtd`.  Is `Failed to parse a schema` a clue?  Shouldn't that be `Failed to parse a DTD` or is this just a generic error message?

UPDATE:

Even when I point XJC directly at a local .DTD file, I get the same error.   Here's proof XJC found the file but never attempted to read the file:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced the same issue.

Check this page, it helps to me to fixed it

https://github.com/IntershopCommunicationsAG/jaxb-gradle-plugin/issues/9

Comment: Here's some documentation describing the `enableExternalEntityProcessing` system property: https://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.4/xjc-mojo.html